# Batch script to list all empty subfolders to file for the path given (trying to fix File Not Found error and path problems)

Tags: batch-file, path, file-not-found

I'm trying to write a batch script that will list all empty subfolders for the path given to a file.

It seems to be mostly working, but there are some problems I can't figure out how to fix.

When I loop through subfolders, it somehow adds points at the end of the path. I believe, that's the reason of the "File Not Found" it also gives as a result.

Also, if I give a path with spaces, it says that the folder does not exist. At the same time, if there are spaces not in the path given but in its child directory, the script handles it well.

Here is the script:

```
@Echo off

setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

IF EXIST List.txt del /F List.txt

::No path given
set "root=%~1"
echo Path given: %root%
if not defined root (
    echo No path given!
    GOTO:EOF
)

::The folder does not exist
if exist %root%\* (
echo:
) else (
    echo No such folder!
    GOTO:EOF
)

::Is folder empty?
echo Is folder empty?
FOR /R "%root%" %%G in (.) DO (
    set "folder=%%G"
    call :testFILE
)
GOTO:EOF

:testFILE
for /F %%i in ('dir /b /A-D "%folder%\*"') do exit /b
REM if you're here, directory has no files
echo %folder% has no files
call :testDIR
exit /b

:testDIR
for /F %%i in ('dir /b /A:D "%folder%\*"') do exit /b
REM if you're here, directory has no directories
echo "%folder%" is totally empty >> List.txt
exit /b
```

Some help with fixing the errors would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally figured it out!

```
@echo off

setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

if exist List.txt del /F List.txt

::No path given
set "root=%~1"
if not defined root (
    echo:
    echo No path given!
    GOTO:EOF
)

::The folder does not exist
if exist %root%\* (
GOTO write_path
) else (
    echo:
    echo No such folder!
    GOTO:EOF
)

:write_path
::Write the given path
echo:
echo Path given: %root%

::Is folder empty?
for /D /r "%root%" %%D in (.) do (
    dir /A /B "%%~fD" 2>nul | findstr "^" >nul || echo %%~fD >> List.txt
)
GOTO:EOF
```

The last part was a bit tricky...

Look here for some explanations about it:

[SS64.com - Command Line Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

[SS64.com - FINDSTR Command](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)